# Grunt CLI installs, but not available

Tags: ubuntu, gruntjs, npm, grunt-cli

Working on Ubuntu 15.04, trying to install the Grunt CLI (`sudo npm install grunt-cli -g`), which works like a dream. The issue comes when trying to execute `grunt` in any directory. No error is given, the command just doesn't work. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "execute `grunt` in any file"? What command are you using exactly that's not doing anything?

Comment: In a directory where grunt has been installed using npm (via it's package.json) and a Gruntfile.js is available, using the `grunt` command should run the default task. But instead nothing happens. Also, running it without a local Gruntfile should provide an error, but that also doesn't happen.

Comment: To clarify, `grunt` is returning absolutely no output, like the command ":"?

Comment: Yeah, nothing. Turns out it was a conflict between node and nodejs, so clearing that up fixed it. Thanks for the link along to the other post.